# Why do I need high fps values in simulations?

Tags: graphics

Sometimes I see NVIDIA simulations with an additional information abbreviated "fps". I've figured out that fps stands for frames per second, but isn't it enough to support 25 fps? Why do I need 60fps ? Most of the movies use 25 fps and not 60. So does anybody know a reason for that ?

Comment: This seems to be a [ux.SE] or maybe [biology.SE] question, not a computer *science* one.

Comment: why _do_ you need 60fps? what movies are you talking about? this is probably too vague to answer in current form & its not clear how to classify the question on current se sites either (because of lack of detail/ info/ bkg)

Comment: @Raphael I agree that this is probably off-topic, but it has nothing to do with UX or biology, it's about display technology. Graphic processing is involved as well, at the edge between science and technology.

Comment: @Gilles Well the reason of having *30/60 FPS* is purely based on how our physical eyes work and it's limitations. In that sense the reason is how we perceive our environment and isn't a technological one.

Comment: fyi cinema/ theatre movies use 24fps! is there an _implicit_ question here like "why do movies look better at higher fps"? that actually is subjective; some major directors have come out against 60fps etc saying they dont like the effect in their movies.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a *cinematography* question, but what makes it interesting for computer science is that it does influence computer graphics. Computer graphics, as Steve Hollasch famously said, is the only area of science where if it looks right, it is right. So we do need to understand what it means for something to look right.

The question that you're really trying to ask is why movies look smooth even at low frame rates like 24fps, given that our eyes have a much higher effective frame rate. The persistence of vision effect should mean that if a character or object is moving, it would be seen as multiple instances of the same object, an effect known as "strobing".

The reason why it was never a problem in chemically-photographed movies is a device called the rotary disc shutter. Photographic film requires that the shutter be open for a certain amount of time, however for a moving film this presents a problem. A rotary disc shutter is a circular plate with a sector of around 180 degrees cut from it, which rotates in front of the film plate. While the shutter is open, light falls on the film. While it's closed, the frame can be advanced.

The shutter angle is one of the variables that a film-era cinematographer could control. It represents how much of the 1/24th of a second the film is exposed for. If the angle is large and the subject is moving fast, rather than seeing two copies, you see motion blur. A point becomes a line, and that line represents the motion of the subject.

Changing the shutter angle affects the exposure time and the amount of motion blur. A smaller angle means the exposure time is shorter (so you may need to use faster film or brighter lights), but the blur is less.

So a fast-moving point moving in a straight line would appear, on film, as a series of "dashes" which are colinear. The answer to the question, why film looks smooth despite the low frame rate, is that the film looks smooth *because our brains can follow that line*, and hence interpret the motion correctly.

(As an aside, TV cameras worked differently, but they had similar analogue properties which meant that you got motion blur.)

Animators quickly worked all this out. Cartoons are inherently unrealistic, so we accept a certain amount of unreality, but animators learned how much you could move an object before strobing took over. If fast motion was needed, they would have to blur manually, using drawings which mimicked temporal subsampling, were distorted in a way that simulated motion blur, or used speedlines, drybrush, and whatever other manual techniques worked.

The image following shows a great combination of some of these techniques. At 24fps, this wouldn't register.

[image: Manual motion blur]

This has implications for computer graphics, both for computer-generated imagery and digital movie cameras. What chemical cameras get for free, digital images must produce somehow.

Rendering fast motion at 24fps, and retaining the illusion of smoothness, requires rendering motion blur. Doing it "right" can be extremely expensive, because it interacts with hidden surface removal in nontrivial ways. (Consider a spinning top with a pattern on it. As time moves on, different parts of the top become visible.)

This is why computer animated movies (where frames are not produced in real-time) tend to look smoother than video games even though the frame rate of a movie is lower. Video games have recently started using screen-space approximations to motion blur, and they can help a lot, but there is usually still apparent strobing.

One of the interesting things about digital cameras is that the "degree of blur" control is effectively decoupled from the "amount of light exposure" control. A modern cinematographer can control these variables independently, where a film cinematographer would have to manipulate them together.

The choice of shutter angle was (and still is) often made for artistic as well as practical reasons. Famously, Janusz Kamiński used a 45 degree shutter angle for some of the shots in *Saving Private Ryan*, which had the effect of making action scenes appear *less* smooth, and hence more jarring, gritty, and frightening (Kamiński used the word "staccato") compared with most action films.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky part is "enough". Although it is sufficient to have a fluent visual effect with merely 22-26 fps (which is what movies commonly use), you will notice a much more comfortable and soothing experience with much higher fps.

Youtube supports both 30 and 60 fps. You could try to find a video that **is prepared for 60fps** and play it twice with different fps (by changing playback resolution/fps in youtube player). I am sure you will see the difference in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Most LCD panels have a refresh rate of 60 Hz, i.e. the screen is refreshed 60 times per second. Video looks better when the number of screen refreshes between two successive frames is constant, otherwise the frame rate will look jittery. That makes 30 fps and 60 fps good choices, whereas 25 fps would cause jitter. Obviously a larger value provides more control (but values above 60fps would be useless except with a screen that refreshes faster), so it will in principle look nicer (there's no guarantee that the difference will be visible though).